# What's the probability of dividing the chessboard into several subareas such that each subarea contains only one ball?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose I have a chessboard which contains $M \times N$ grids. There are $K$ different balls on the chessboard, and the location indices is defined as $ (i^{k},j^{k})$ for the $k$th ball, where $i^k$ denotes the row index and $j^k$ denotes the column index. Denote the overall row index set as $\mathcal{A} =\{1,2,\ldots, M\}$ and the overall column index set $\mathcal{B} =\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$.

Now, I want to divide the chessboard into $\frac{M}{X} \times \frac{N}{Y} $ disjoint subareas, and each subarea is a $ X \times Y $ mini-chessboard. The way to divide the chessboard is confined to select row $X$ row indices from $\mathcal{A}$ and the $Y$ indices from $\mathcal{B}$ each time.

For example, suppose $M=N=4,X=2=Y=2$, the first ball is located as $(1,2)$ and the second ball is located as $(1,4)$. I first partition the $\mathcal{A}$ into $X=2$ equal disjoint sets, i.e, $ \mathcal{A}_1 = \{ (1,2)\}$  and $\mathcal{A}_2 = \{ (3,4)\}$. Similarly, the set $\mathcal{B}$ is divided into $Y=2$ disjoint sets, i.e., $ \mathcal{B}_1 = \{ (1,4)\}$  and $\mathcal{B}_2 = \{ (2,3)\}$.I Then I can divide the chessboard into $4$ mini-chessboards, which are $ \mathcal{C}_{mn} = \{ (i,j)| i \in \mathcal{A}_m, j \in \mathcal{B}_n, m = 1,2,n=1,2 \}$. In this case, each mini-chessboard would contain at most a ball.

My question is what is the probability to divide the chessboard such that each mini-chessboard contains at most a single ball? I've tried to use induction but it does no help. Any comments would be appreciated!

Comment: I imagine it could be worked out exactly for small values, for example, when $X=Y=2$ and $2\le K\le 4$, or when $K=2$ more generally. That would be a good starting point. Even writing down trivial or semi-trivial cases (for example, $Y=1$ is simpler but still not completely trivial) should be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. For $K=2$, I'm wondering if I can catrogory the problem into $3$ different case, the first is for balls are located neither in the same row or in the same column; the second is for that balls are located in the same row but not in the same column and the third is for that balls are located in the same column but not in the same row.